# C# 2.0: Can MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod() return null?

Tags: .net, null, c#-2.0

I'm tracking down a NullReferenceException and [the official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getcurrentmethod.aspx) is lacking.

This is C# 2.0 code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at Reflector, it looks like it can:

```csharp
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
public static MethodBase GetCurrentMethod()
{
    StackCrawlMark lookForMyCaller = StackCrawlMark.LookForMyCaller;
    return RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalGetCurrentMethod(ref lookForMyCaller);
}
```

and `InternalGetCurrentMethod` looks like:

```csharp
internal static MethodBase InternalGetCurrentMethod(ref StackCrawlMark stackMark)
{
    RuntimeMethodHandle currentMethod = RuntimeMethodHandle.GetCurrentMethod(ref stackMark);
    if (currentMethod.IsNullHandle())
    {
        return null;
    }
    return RuntimeType.GetMethodBase(currentMethod.GetTypicalMethodDefinition());
}
```